# SQLite compiled flags on iOS (libsqlite3)

Tags: ios, sqlite

What are the compiler flags used with the system version of SQLite, aka libsqlite3? Certain features like loading plugins at runtime can be disabled via compiler flags.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question - As of iOS 8.3 here are the flags. As you can see it includes RTree but disables extensions, even though we can use frameworks on iOS now.

```
ENABLE_FTS3
ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS
ENABLE_LOCKING_STYLE=1
ENABLE_RTREE
MAX_MMAP_SIZE=0
OMIT_AUTORESET
OMIT_BUILTIN_TEST
OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION
SYSTEM_MALLOC
THREADSAFE=2
```

Comment: Could you please add the source of this information?